# Node.js: What is the guarantee that we reply to the right req in asynchronous programming?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In all most all `node.js` tutorial I can see this pattern of coding.

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
 User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send(user);
 });
});
```

Now this line `res.send(user)` is scaring me. `User.findById` is `asynchronous` and this api end point may get simultaneous hits and **what is the guarantee that we have right `res` at the time of we reply to the `req`.**

As of now I am creating `closure` to maintain the variable value.

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
 User.findById(req.body.id, function(res){
  return function(err, user) {
   if (err) throw err;
   res.send(user);
  }
 }(res));
});
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to add closure protection for `req` and `res`.  They are already properly scoped to one callback and are not shared or accessible with code running from other requests.

The `app.get()` function call has already created a closure for the `req` and `res` objects.  So, any code within that callback or called from that callback and passed those arguments is guaranteed to get the right objects, no matter how much async coding is going on anywhere.

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {

  // This is already a unique closure right here with unique copies of
  // the req and res arguments.  These arguments cannot be accessed
  // by any other request or by any code out of this scope
  // unless you copy them yourself to some shared location
  // with concurrency access issues

  User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(user);
  });
});
```

The only other thing that has to happen correctly is for node.js to never reuse those `req` and `res` objects for other requests that might happen while this one is being processed asynchronously.  And, it DOES guarantee that.  `req` and `res` are created new for each request.

Furthermore, there isn't even a way from one request to get access to the `req` or `res` from another request unless YOU somehow share it inappropriately (like stuffing it in a shared module level variable).  So, as long as you only use the `req` or `res` directly from the callback in the lexical scope or you pass them to a function you are calling and none of your code actually saves them someplace that has concurrency access issues, then there are no issues.

So, to summarize.   node.js itself does not have any concurrency issues with the `req` and `res` objects.  ***So, as long as you don't create a problem by storing `req` or `res` in some shared location that has concurrency access issues from your own code, this is not a problem.***

---

**Wrong Code Example**

Just to show you what wrong code would look like that does cause a problem:

```
var _res;

app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
 _res = res;
 User.findById(_req.body.id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  _res.send(user);
 });
});

app.get('/account', function (req, res) {
 _res = res;
 User.findById(req.body.account, function(err, account) {
  if (err) throw err;
  _res.send(account);
 });
});
```

Here, the code is assigning `res` to a higher scoped and shared variable and then attempting to use it after an async call.  This would be bad and does create a concurrency issue.  But, this isn't an issue with node.js per se, but an issue with bad code that isn't aware of proper concurrency design.  And, there's no reason to copy a variable being used in an async operation to a higher and shared scope either.  If it needs to be elsewhere, it should be passed as an argument as that will keep it unique per request.

---

Here are some reading references on "Javascript lexical scope".

[What You Should Know About Javascript Scope](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/20/javascript-scope-closures/)

[MDN: Lexical Scope and Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

[You Don't Know JS: Scopes & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch2.md)

[Everything You Wanted to Know About Javascript Scope](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

Comment: Thank you so much. These scoping concept in javascript is kind of new to me as I come from Java background shifting mindset is too difficult.. Can you please refer some book or blog to learn more about these things..

Comment: @Praveen - I added a few reading references to the end of my answer.  You can find lots of other articles with a Google search for "Javascript lexical scope".  Because of local function definitions and inline anonymous function definitions, you can do really useful things to take advantage of Javascript's lexical scoping so it is a very good thing to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is both incorrect and unnecessary. In this case the lexical scoping takes care of what you think is an issue.

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) { // <- the `res` here
 User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send(user); // is the same `res` here
 });
});
```

due to the already existing closure created by definition of the function passed as the callback.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think your scare is unfounded. When a request comes in each one gets its own reference to the callback function you pass to it. Which in this case is the one that handles the response. This function gets the `res` object, which is then used in the next callback function passed to the `findById` due to lexical scoping in JavaSript.

```
app.get('/user', function (req, res) { 
 User.findById(req.body.id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.send(user); // res here is unique for every new request,no need to worry :)
 });
});
```